# issue with Lora CSMA/CA management )

Tags: networking, lorawan

Is there a way to manipulate CSMA/CA or CSMA/CD code in Lorawan, to make an application that can manage the different network at the same time anybody has experience with this issue

Comment: CSMA is usually built into the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

A LoRa device has no way to detect that a message didn't reach its destination because of a collision. That is why CSMA/CD/CA is not implemented.
What can be implemented is called LBT (Listen Before Talk) however, LBT does not bring to much benefit either, since the sending device cannot listen by the "ears" of the potential receiver (that could be several km away from the sender). It could happen that although the sender does not hear any interference at its neighbourhood, the receiver's environment (that is far away) is noisy and therefore the message is lost.

The common technic that is used in LoRaWAN networks to avoid collision is a Duty Cycle rule. For example: you can implement a rule for all LoRa devices that forces that they mustn't occupy the air interface for longer than 1% of the time.